# How can I sort product listing by "best value", that is, an attribute calculated from (price divided by size)?

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I have several homogeneous products of varying sizes, in grams.  I would like to provide a value by which the customer could sort the product listing by best value, as calculated from price divided by mass/weight/size.  I already have one attribute which is the size in grams and is defined by a number followed by a 'g' (eg, 100g, 500g), so to make it easier, I suppose I would create another attribute that reflects the weight without the 'g' appended to the value.

However, I don't know if it's possible to automatically calculate value with attributes  (ie, create an attribute that automatically calculates the price/weight value without any more work on my part).  Or, do I have to do some custom code, and where would that be?  Any suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: It may be possible to auto-fill an attribute using javascript. e.g. if you have an attribute "weight" and "price". you may calculate "bestprice" = weight/price and auto fill this attribute using javascript and press the save button

Comment: just so I understand, this proposed auto-fill action would occur within the backend?  Perhaps initiated by a new button that I create on the catalog product listing page?

Comment: you may create a separate button for this or call the script on "save" button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an custom module. 
In this module you have to create an observer on "catalog_product_save_after" event.

As i don't know which Magento version are you using, i will just give you some snippets that may or may not work in your current version, but will definitely help you understand.

This is how your custom module 'config.xml' should look like:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <calculateBestValue>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Foo_Bar_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>calcBestValue</method>
                </calculateBestValue>
            </observers>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

And this is your 'Observer.php' model.

```
public function calcBestValue(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    // Here you can access your productData and do your logic
    // Ex: $_product->getData('weight');        
    // Ex: $_product->getData('price');
    // Ex: $_product->getData('mass');
    // Ex: $_product->getData('size');

    /* Your best value logic here */

    // After that you just need to set the bestValue attribute in the product

    $_product->setBestValue($bestValue);
}
```

You will need to create an catalog attribute for "Best Value" and associate it in an attribute set.

After the "best value logic" is ready you just need to enable your custom attribute for sorting in product list. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9928/adding-custom-attributes-to-product-list